# Help understanding a SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have difficulty understanding `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 0 = ...` in the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM incTable 
WHERE myTable.export_date <= incTable.export_date 
AND myTable.colA = incTable.colA 
AND myTable.colB = incTable.colB 
AND myTable.colC = incTable.colC)
```

From my understanding, usually in the `WHERE` clause, a column is evaluated against some other entity (i.e. another column or value). What does it mean to be evaluating against two numbers (i.e `WHERE 0 = 5`)? Will `SELECT * FROM myTable` always return the contents of `myTable` regardless of what the outcome of the `WHERE` clause in the above SQL statement?

Comment: What happens when you run query?

Comment: I don't have the database as of right now to run queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0=5 would be false for "all" rows, so wouldn't return anything.  If the subquery doesn't return any rows, you'll get all the rows in myTable.

This is a weird way of doing EXISTS().

Comment: Indeed, A suboptimal way of doing `NOT EXISTS`. That is more efficient as it can exit as soon as the first matching row is found rather than continuing to count them all (at least in theory - No idea about `MySQL` implementation of the two)

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking too hard.  The entire select statement in parentheses could be moved to the other side of the equals sign and it would still work...

it could just as easily be written as

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE  (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM incTable WHERE myTable.export_date <= incTable.export_date 
        AND myTable.colA = incTable.colA AND myTable.colB = incTable.colB AND myTable.colC =
incTable.colC) = 0
```

To simplify, say the entire SELECT Count(*)... statement is replaced by a variable named "@subquery"  in pseudo-sql it would look like

Select * From myTable where 0 = @subquery

or

Select * From myTable where @subquery = 0

It's just like algebra.  You can flip the items on the side of the "=" operator without changing the meaning of the statement. (if a=b then b=a) - [The Symmetric Propertyof Equality](http://library.thinkquest.org/2647/algebra/post.htm)

Effectively it's searching for records in `myTable` without matching records in `incTable`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the where clause will evaluate to true if the count subquery returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

It just selects the rows from myTable that don't have any corresponding rows (determined by what's in the where clause in the subquery) in incTable, hence the `where 0 = select count(*) ...` . Maybe if you reverse it, it makes more sense to you `where select count(*) ... = 0` (but basically the order doesn't matter).

Comment: I suspect the literal was put at the front so it didn't get lost.

Comment: @MarkD: Could be, or he simply follows the same logic in his programming. There seems to be a trend to put constants on the left side of equations these days (well, I see it popping up more frequently as of late anyway :p).

Answer (score 0):

The second select statement aggregates and counts its results.
As you assumed it will return a number.